# jQuery date picker year 1927 format dd mm y issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery DatePicker for format **dd mm y** breaking

I type in 01 01 27 it breaks it doesn't shows the date selected in calendar

Is it a jQuery bug ?

It accepts all values above year 1927

**HTML**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**JS**

```
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd mm y",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: "-100Y",
    maxDate: "-18Y"
});
```

```js
$(function () {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd mm y",
   
     changeMonth: true,
 
       changeYear: true,
  
      minDate: "-100Y",
 
       maxDate: "-18Y"
 
   });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the date formats for datepicker? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: yes what i want is of the format dd mm yy so the best format suited is dd mm y

Comment: I can enter any digits I like, and can initially only see a 10 year range, 99–89. But if I select the lowest year, the next range is ±10 years from that. Sometimes the picker obscures the field, other times not.

Answer (score 0):

looks like yearRange is something you can use:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd mm y",

changeMonth: true,

changeYear: true,

yearRange: "c-100:c-18"

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: I need to type your suggestion doesn't allows me to type

Comment: It isnot a best practice as well so each year I need to go into code and change this range ehh

Comment: when you go more than 100 years back, looks like a bug.

Comment: Hai I am not able to type in the textbox I think you need to tweak it

Comment: _"when you go more than 100 years back, looks like a bug"_ it's not a bug, it is a limitation caused by using only two digits for a year.  Does `27` mean 1927 or 2027? This is a classic Y2K issue, you may want to search for ways this has been handled, because it's basically _up to you_ how you want to deal with it. **And** if you accept 2-digit years you should still _store them_ as 4-digit years, unless you want to re-create the y2k problem.

Comment: "28 10 89" is treated as 28 October, 1889.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer

adding
`shortYearCutoff: "1",` solves my problem

For more details check [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-shortYearCutoff)